# creating a matrix or a list of lists with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I working through a tutorial working on lists and using tic-tac-toe.

I am given a string like: XOXOXOXXO

And I'd like to convert this into a matrix or a list of list, 
for example:

`tic_tac_toe= [[ 'X', 'O', 'X'],
               [ 'O', 'X', 'O'],
               [ 'O', 'X', 'X']]`

I can get this as a 'list', but I can't get this as a list of lists.

I've been searching various posts, and one challenge is I see a lot that are 5 or 7 years old, and I have to wonder how relevant some of the answers still are, and I haven't been able to make work those prior recommendations.

```
player_actions = 'XO_OOX_X_'

cells = list()

print('Before loop:', player_actions)

for char in player_actions:
    cells.insert(0, ''.join(char.split()))

# Output
print('After loop:', cells)

Output example:
Before loop: XOXOXOXXO
After loop: ['O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X']

Goal: [['O', 'X', 'X'],['O', 'X', 'O'],['O', 'X', 'X']]
```

Comment: Your desired output `[['O', 'X', 'X'],['O', 'X', 'O'],['O', 'X', 'X']]` doesn't seem to match your input string `XOXOXOXXO`

Comment: piecing together the above from several runs, and I grabbed the wrong parts for illustration. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `slicing`, create a batch of equally distributed elements:

```
s = 'XOXOXOXXO'
splitted = [s[x:x+3] for x in range(0,len(s),3)]
print([[i] for i in splitted])
```

one-liner:

```
print([[i] for i in [s[x:x+3] for x in range(0,len(s),3)]]) # [['XOX'], ['OXO'], ['XXO']] 
print([[i for i in s[x:x+3]] for x in range(0,len(s),3)])   # [['X', 'O', 'X'], ['O', 'X', 'O'], ['X', 'X', 'O']]
```

Comment: I kept trying this with standard for loops but would run into index out of range errors. Thanks for sharing the list comprehension version.

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy array and reshape it after that

#### code

```py
import numpy as np

arr = ['O','X','O','X','X','O','X','X','O'] #let's take this list as an example

arr = np.array(arr).reshape(3,3) #this creates a 3x3 matrix of the given list

arr = arr.tolist() #if you want to convert numpy array back to list

print(arr)

#output
# [['O', 'X', 'O'], ['X', 'X', 'O'], ['X', 'X', 'O']]
```

Comment: I saw the numpy modules mentioned with matrix. I was trying to do this without importing a module, but this works pretty well. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: @Wolftales Happy to help, just my two cents I thinks it's better to use numpy when dealing with multi dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your actual desired output for

```
player_actions = 'XOXOXOXXO'
```

is

```
[['X', 'O', 'X'], ['O', 'X', 'O'], ['X', 'X', 'O']]
```

you can generate that using a nested list comprehension:

```
cells = [[c for c in player_actions[i:i+3]] for i in range(0, len(player_actions), 3)]
```

Comment: This was my intent. Thank you.